# Why Last value of a class object String assign to first one object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

[Click Here to see Dartpad Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmIZX.png)

```
void main(){
Student file1 = Student.empty;
Student file2 = Student.empty;
file1.name = 'ABC';
file2.name = 'DEF';
print(file1.name);
print(file2.name);
}
class Student{
String name;
Student({
required this.name,
});
static Student empty = Student(name: '');
}
```

**Output Value**

DEF
DEF

**Expected Value**

ABC
DEF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, because you are using the same `static` instance of `Student`, since the static field is shared across all instances of `Student`.

So your variables `file1` and `file2` are referencing the same single  instance of `Student`.

You may want to use a factory constructor instead:

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors

```dart
void main() {
  Student file1 = Student.empty();
  Student file2 = Student.empty();
  file1.name = 'ABC';
  file2.name = 'DEF';
  print(file1.name);
  print(file2.name);
}

class Student {
  String name;
  Student({
    required this.name,
  });
  
  factory Student.empty() {
    return Student(name: '');
  }
}
```

Comment: It really works! Thank You So Much. I really appreciate it <3